# Do Italian citizens need a visa to enter Dubai?

Tags: visas, dubai, visa-free-entry, italian-citizens, doha

I'll travel for holidays from Doha to Dubai with an Italian passport. 
My Qatar visa allows me multiple entries.
Do I need a visa to enter Dubai for a short weekend stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Italian citizens are eligible for a 30-day UAE visa on arrival free of charge.](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) You can then extend this for another 30 days by paying a fee.

> #### Visas on Arrival
>
> If your country of nationality appears on the list below, no advance visa arrangements are required to visit the UAE. Simply disembark your flight at Dubai International Airport and proceed to Immigration, where your passport will be stamped with a 30-day visit visa free of charge. This can be extended for an additional 30 days at an additional charge.
>
> [image: UAE countries visa on arrival]

Comment: in addition, even if he was not Italian - he was eligible for the evisa which is for GCC residents.